# JavaScript&jQuery: переход на следующую итерацию цикла при завершении анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приведённый ниже код должен сменяеть картинки на слайдере. Как только будет достигнута последняя картинка, необходимо начать показ картинок сначала и так до бесконечности.

```
function launchSlider(){

    for (let i = 0; i<imagesCount; i++) {

        console.log(i);

        // текущая картинка "выцветает"
        $allSliderImages.eq(i).fadeOut(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing'); 
        // следующая картинка синхронно появляется
        $allSliderImages.eq(i+1).fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing');  

        // как только следующей становится последняя картинка, сбрасываем счётчик 
        // (при входе в следующую итерацию будет -1 + 1 = 0)
        if (i === imagesCount - 1) {
            i = -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Однако, в данном коде переход на следующую итерацию цикла осуществляется не дожидаясь завершеня анимации и таким образом выполняется несколько итераций в секунду. Естественно, что браузер подвисает.

Как сделать так, чтобы переход на следующую итерацию цикла осуществлялся только после завершения анимации?

На всякий случай напомню, что согласно [документации jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), при применении эффектов к двум разным элементам они стартуют одновременно, а потому если будем использовать callback, то если ли разница, к какой анимации его добавлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function launchSlider(){
    var i = 0;
    function x(){
        // текущая картинка "выцветает"
        $allSliderImages.eq(i).fadeOut(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing'); 
        // Следующую надо вычислять лучше так
        var next = (i + 1) % imagesCount;
        // следующая картинка синхронно появляется
        // После анимации снова вызываем функцию x
        $allSliderImages.eq(next).fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing', x);  
        i = next;
    }
    // Первый запуск функции
    x();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Не могли бы Вы добавить комментарий о том, как именно Ваш код позволяет решить задачу? Я вижу, Вы использовали замыкание и ещё применили какой-то интересный способ вычисления номера следующей картинки.

Comment: (i + 1) % imagesCount - это получение следующей картинки. При достижении imagesCount счёт начинается с 0.

Comment: fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing', x); - планирует выполнение следующей итерации на конец анимации

Comment: Сам launchSlider надо запустить при загрузке странице как-то так $(function(){launchSlider();});

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! А почему Вы назвали внутреннюю функцию `x()`? Какое с точи зрения архитектуры Вашего решения можно выбрать логически понятное имя для данной фунции?

Comment: NextStep() или NextIteration(). Или просто ChangeImage()

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
    var items = $("img"),
        len = items.length,
        i = len - 1,
        duration = 1000,
        pause = 2000;
    items.hide().last().show();
    (function Reload() {
        items.eq(i).delay(pause).fadeOut(duration, Reload);
        i = ++i % len;
        items.eq(i).delay(pause).fadeIn(duration)
    })()
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Не могли бы Вы добавить комментарий к своему решению? Мне пока что не очень понятна такая архитектура кода.